# micronaut HttpResponse reading body text

Tags: java, groovy, httpresponse, micronaut

Trying to capture the response.body() text which is actually xml.

```
@Get(uri="/testxml")
public String testxml() {
    System.out.println("Reading Response body test");
    HttpResponse response = streamClient.test();
    CompositeByteBuf content = (CompositeByteBuf) response.body();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[content.readableBytes()];
    int readerIndex = content.readerIndex();
    content.getBytes(readerIndex, bytes);
    String read = new String(bytes).trim();
    //System.out.println("RES"+ read);
    return read;

}
```

I have the above code in this [java micronaut application](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/micronaut-java-groovy-comparison/blob/master/test-java/src/main/java/comparison/java/groovy/controller/OrdersController.java#L63-L76) and again [in this groovy application](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/micronaut-java-groovy-comparison/blob/master/test-groovy/src/main/groovy/comparison.java.groovy/controller/OrdersController.groovy#L39-L52). and it appears when I hit the Java application http://localhost:8081/orders/testxml  for the very first time I see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><current_orders><order><name>a1</name><description>a1</description><price>12.2200000000000006394884621840901672840118408203125</price></order></current_orders>
```

but any additional attempts on the java results in

```
{"message":"Internal Server Error: refCnt: 0"}
```

and trace shows:

```
Reading Response body test
09:32:04.799 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: refCnt: 0
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.ensureAccessible(AbstractByteBuf.java:1446)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkIndex(AbstractByteBuf.java:1376)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkDstIndex(AbstractByteBuf.java:1401)
        at io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.getBytes(CompositeByteBuf.java:854)
        at io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.getBytes(CompositeByteBuf.java:44)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.getBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:487)
        at io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.getBytes(CompositeByteBuf.java:1744)
        at comparison.java.groovy.controller.OrdersController.testxml(OrdersController.java:71)
        at comparison.java.groovy.controller.$OrdersControllerDefinition$$exec4.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:145)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$BeanExecutionHandle.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:2401)
        at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:237)
        at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:123)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildResultEmitter$13(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1255)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCreate.subscribeActual(FlowableCreate.java:71)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:37)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.subscribeActual(FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.java:32)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14429)
        at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.lambda$subscribe$0(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:53)
        at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:53)
        at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.subscribe(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:53)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14426)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker$BooleanRunnable.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:260)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:225)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The Groovy application doesn't appear to ever actually load anything up and upon further inspection I noticed that in Java the raw representation of:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[content.readableBytes()];
System.out.println("Bytes = "+bytes);
```

Comes out something like `[h87aa..` where as groovy version shows `[00 11 00 ]` a long array of numbers.

Ultimately I am trying to send xml from 1 app and parse it on the other and perhaps there is a much much easier way. Currently stuck as to why this odd behaviour is happening

Comment: I have answered the first question, It appears wrapping it around a Single has now made it work every single time. https://github.com/vahidhedayati/micronaut-java-groovy-comparison/commit/ca5f1aa629c46679a06577818f4dcbc33071abe7 this check in has fixed the java app issue - it always now works

Comment: The Groovy issue is also now resolved the actual issue turned out that whilst  the stream client was `Single<HttpResponse<?>> test()`  on Java this worked but under the groovy project this produced `Optional.empty` when asking for `response.body()` after changing the client and controller to call `Single<HttpResponse<CompositeByteBuf>> test();`  this has now fixed the groovy issue as well. under this check in https://github.com/vahidhedayati/micronaut-java-groovy-comparison/commit/a504ae16bb726f437dca4c38abeb1d35d3be38b7  - nothing to be answered now sorry can close